# Selenium sendkeys enter pipe ( | ) for backslash (\)

Tags: selenium, sendkeys

In selenium sendkeys sometimes the backslash ( \ ) is replaced with a pipe ( | ) symbol. this issue is a sporadic issue. 
Below is the code snippet that i have used

```
aItDriver.switchTo().window("[TITLE:Choose File to Upload]");
aItDriver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(new String[]{"I:\Downloads\fileName.txt" + Keys.ENTER});
```

in here we used autoit (aItDriver) driver to enter the file path for file upload screen,

expected output for the file upload screen was :

> I:\Downloads\fileName.txt

But we see the below text entered to the upload window text box in rare cases.

> I:|Downloads\fileName.txt

Could someone give an explanation to this sporadic issue, and if there is a correct way to enter the given text or fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

@Marlan

depending on the language that you use, there is few solutions to fix the absolute path.

In java you can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("myFile.txt");
    Path absolutePath = path.toAbsolutePath();

    System.out.println(absolutePath.toString());
}
```

After that you can just used element.sendKeys(absolutePath.toString()); 
to upload file

Using JavaScript:

```
const path = require('path');
let absoluteFilePath = path.resolve('myFile.txt');

element(by.id('something').sendKeys(absoluteFilePath);
```